# How can I load multiple textures asynchronously with a callback in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Loading a single texture with a callback is easy, eg:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture1 = loader.load("https://i.imgur.com/UiTMJzv.png", process);

//called only after texture1 is loaded
function process(){

}
```

The question is how can I load multiple textures asynchronously (and not sequentially) and only call a processing function when all have been loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [THREE.LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager) for this:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager( function() {

    // this onLoad callback is executed when both textures are loaded

} );

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );
var texture1 = loader.load( 'texture1.png' );
var texture2 = loader.load( 'texture2.png' );
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! 
BTW the three.js example that is listed on documentation does not work (it raises errors): https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_scene

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. The dead link is now removed in `dev` https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/d816a4d224d562065295c3d63f868e0031db614a